# Limit no of files to upload in tomitrescak:meteor-uploads package

Tags: meteor

i have used this `https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads` package to upload files in meteor.

there is some properties like 
-maxPostSize
-minFileSize
-maxFileSize

but nothing like to limit no of files to upload.
is it possible ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you check the number of items in Items collection you can manage kind of limit.
My2c (I'm a newbye in Meteor stuff)
R.